# Periodic pc micro stuttering?

Tags: windows-10

So I've had my PC since Late Octoberish, and recently I've been every now and then had these micro stutters where the computer will for like 3-5 seconds have a 100 ms of like stuttering. This is easy to tell when I have a video on my 4k display and the video doesn't pause via YouTube but stutters and audio cuts out for a brief period. And if I'm playing the game the same thing.

Does anyone have any idea on troubleshooting I don't think it's a heating issue? Though that may be the issue and if so how could i diagnose and fix this issue?

[Full Specs](https://pcpartpicker.com/user/Buffet_Time/saved/mrwTHx)

CPU I had at 4.1GHz i brought down back to 3.7 no fix, i had my RAM at 3000MHz i have brough it down to 2733MHz

Any and all help would be greatly appreciated because it's quite annoying as you could imagine given the specs of the computer.

Here is a dump of system info from hwinfo including temps. [HWInfo Sensor Status CSV download](https://linustechtips.com/main/applications/core/interface/file/attachment.php?id=432469) The only thing i see that may be an issue is the temperature of the M.2 NVME ssd however i'm not sure if the storage temperature matters that much.

That's all I can think of in terms of things that would help someone remedy this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seemingly Uninstalling the Gigabyte Aorus Engine software which i was using has fixed this issue.